# How I can assign a variable to the radiobutton again?

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I have a problem with radiobutton. Application uses it when reading data from the database. Reads the user's gender. This function works when a user is logged on and selects the appropriate button. The first time you read correctly, but the second program returns an exception NullReferenceException was unhandled.

C#

```
 if (napis.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString() == "Mężczyzna")
        {
            MezczyznaRadioButton2.IsChecked = true;
            KobietaRadioButton2.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            KobietaRadioButton2.IsChecked = true;
            MezczyznaRadioButton2.IsChecked = false;
        }
```

Comment: Your title and question doesnt match fix it pls

Answer (score 1):

One of the following are `null`:

- `napis`
- `napis.ItemArray`
- `napis.ItemArray.GetValue(5)` - the return value would be `null` here

Use the debugger to determine that.